# How to initially insert documents into Mongoose (The first time)

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have a store, with 8 items, and varieties of each of those items.  Here is my Schema for the item:

```
var productSchema = new Schema({
  color: {
    type: String
  },
  flavor: {
    type: String
  },
  edition: {
    type: String
  },
  offset : {
    type: String
  },
  size: {
    type: String
  }
});
```

So now I am at the point where I need to fill out my digital store with the amount of items.  I am wondering what is the correct way to do this (and how, in the future I would add more of each time of product to my "store" i.e. my database).

Here are the ways I can see doing it:

Add the items directly using something like Robomongo or just `mongo` itself (which would involve making some long loop for each of the types of items I have)

or creating a node App which would be run one time and would go through the process of inserting and saving the documents just as if they were added one at a time.

As I have never done this I do not know how people stock their database with their initial supplies of items and would appreciate any insight.  Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I personally setup some migration files and use this npm package to do so:

[MIGRATE](https://www.npmjs.com/package/migrate)